# Can all three numbers $\ n\ \ n^2-1\ \ n^2+1\ $ be fine (as opposed to coarse)?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\ n\ $ be an arbitrary natural number ($\ 1\ 2\ \ldots).\ $ Then

- $\ n\ $ is coarse $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $ there exists a prime divisor $p$ of $\ n\ $ such that $\ p^3>n.$;
- $\ n\ $ is a p-cube $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $ the positive cubical root of $\ n\ $ is a prime number;
- $\ n\ $ is fine $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ p^3<n\ $
  for every prime divisor $\ p\ $ of $\ n$.

**Example:**   Natural $\ 64\ $ and
$$ 4095=64^2-1\ = 3^2\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot13 $$
are both fine. However,

$$ 4097=64^2+1=17\cdot241  $$

is coarse.

**QUESTION**   Does there exist a fine natural number $\ n\ $ such that both $\ n^2-1\ $ and $\ n^2+1\ $ are fine too? (*My guess: perhaps NOT*).

Also, I don't expect that there is any p-cube $\ n\ $ such that both  $\ n^2-1\ $ and $\ n^2+1\ $ are fine.

On the other hand, I believe that there are infinitely many coarse $\ n\ $ such that both  $\ n^2-1\ $ and $\ n^2+1\ $ are fine (as rare as they may be).

Comment: I expect the answer to be positive: being fine has positive probability (related to Dickman distribution), and it is unlikely that being of the $n^2+1$ changes this dramatically or that these events are highly dependent

Comment: When $\ n\ $ is fine then it either has several different prime divisors or some divisors are raised to a power in $\ n.\ $ Thus, in the first case, these prime divisors are avoided by both $\ n^2\pm1,\ $ and in the other case, the powers $\pm1\ $ tend to lean toward large prime divisors -- my vague intuitions.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, Thank you for catching my error.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, I fixed my strange error, thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$n = 2673$ has largest prime factor $11$ whose cube is $1331$.
$n^2 - 1 = 7144928$ has largest prime factor $191$ whose cube is $6967871$.
$n^2 + 1 = 7144930$ has largest prime factor $61$ whose cube is $226981$.

Comment: $n=10625$ is the only other example up to 12000.

Comment: I risked (and lost :-)). One could still try for infinitely many examples. @FedorPetrov, see above, feels that there should be an infinite sequence. –

Comment: 2673, 10625, 12168, 14651, 24167, 28800, 32085, 34162, 48279, 50692, 59892, 60928, 61347, 61952, 64960, 66125, 66339, 70400, 71995, 74704, 80730, 83028, 89424, 93024, 96348, .... Not yet in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=2673%2C+10625%2C+12168%2C+14651&sort=&language=&go=Search).  @WlodAA would you like to contribute it?

Comment: @RobertIsrael. that's very kind of you. I have all kinds of problems with my Internet and computer system.  I'd be very grateful if you'd like to insert this sequence into OEIS.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, first of all, thank you for finding and sharing your sequence with MO (including me). It looks as Fedor Petrov was right.

Comment: [OEIS sequence A345896](https://oeis.org/A345896).

Answer (score 5):

For any $k\in\mathbb{N}$, the number $n=2^3\cdot3^{72k}$ works:

Obviously, $n$ itself is fine.

For $n^2-1 = 2^6\cdot3^{144k}-1 = (2^2\cdot 3^{48 k} + 2\cdot 3^{24 k} + 1)(2^2\cdot 3^{48 k}-2\cdot 3^{24 k} + 1)(2\cdot3^{24 k} + 1) (2\cdot3^{24 k} - 1)$, the first factor is divisible by $7$, the others are small, hence $n^2-1$ is fine.

For $n^2+1 = 2^6\cdot3^{144k}+1 = (2^2\cdot3^{48k}+2^2\cdot3^{36k}+2\cdot3^{24k}+2\cdot3^{12k}+1)(2^2\cdot3^{48k}-2^2\cdot3^{36k}+2\cdot3^{24k}-2\cdot3^{12k}+1)(2\cdot3^{24k}+2\cdot3^{12k}+1)(2\cdot3^{24k}-2\cdot3^{12k}+1)$, the first factor is divisible by $13$, the others are small, hence $n^2+1$ is fine.

Comment: Excellent! A nice elementary approach. This went in a perfect direction; it suggests **general** related results. Perhaps you could use this method in the other thread too. One "simply" select proper exponents and proper bases that go well with the exponents and extra divisors.